# Estado da requisição após fechamento do navegador

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, navegador-de-internet, request

Tenho um projeto Asp.Net MVC e percebi que ao fechar o navegador imediatamente após o início de uma requisição (sem esperar seu devido término), faz com que de alguma forma o servidor não dê continuidade nas próximas linhas de código.

Fiz algumas pesquisas, mas não consegui encontrar a explicação e o funcionamento detalhado disso.

É possível dar continuidade a uma requisição, mesmo depois de fechar o navegador?

Comment: Acredito que seja possível pois já vi acontecer, mas não sei como é feito. rs

Comment: Eu acho que você tá vendo algo errado. Depois de receber a requisição, o servidor trabalha por si só, independentemente do cliente.

Comment: Você está em modo debug?